# rails - Model Methods, (Getting a PaperClip image URL off S3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails 3 app with paperclip. The model looks a little like:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :styles => {
                      :large => '1024x758>',
                      :medium => "200x150#",
                      :thumb => "100x75#",
                      :small => "50x50>"
                    },
                    :default_style => :original,
                    :default_url => '/images/:attachment/default_:style.png',
                    :path => ":instance_id/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
                    :s3_protocol => 'https',
                    :s3_permissions => :private,
                    :use_timestamp => false

def authenticated_url(style = nil, expires_in = 90.minutes)
    AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(attachment.path(style || attachment.default_style), attachment.bucket_name, :expires_in => expires_in, :use_ssl => attachment.s3_protocol == 'https')
end
```

This is called from a user_mailer which is called via delayed_job:

In user_mailer.rb mailer it looks a little something like this:

```
  @comment.attachments.each do |a|
    attachments[a.attachment_file_name] = open(a.authenticated_url()) {|f| f.read }
  end
```

The issue here is that delayed mailer is erroring with:

```
{uninitialized constant Attachment::AWS
/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/app/models/attachment.rb:53:in `authenticated_url'\n/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:41:in 
`conversation_notification'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:430:in 
`method_missing'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `method_missing'\n/
Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in 
`each'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in 
`send'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:216:in `method_missing'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:430:in `method_missing'\n/Users/bhellman/Sites/cline/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:39:in `conversation_notification'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `send_action'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:75:in `process'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:446:in `process'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:441:in `initialize'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:425:in `new'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:425:in `method_missing'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in `send'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in `perform'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:83:in `invoke_job'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:118:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:176:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:102:in `times'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:102:in `work_off'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `start'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:76:in `start'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:73:in `loop'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/worker.rb:73:in `start'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-411719b38c51/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31\n/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'\n/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `require "aws/s3"` in your model.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me more about why that is? When I deliver the mail w/o delayed_job it works fine with just deliver but with delayed_job it errors. I am using the aws s3 gem and am using it for photo uploads for many models. none of them have the aws/s3 being required. So I'm not sure how that fixes the bug? thxs

Comment: I am nt sure, but that it may be possible that the gem may already have been loaded by paper-clip, when you deliver w/o delayed_job.Also delayed_job runs its own instance of the rails env , so if its not properly loaded in your environment or in the class it will error out.

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering if in the authenticated_url method I needed to use self.XXXX ?

Comment: I think that worked. Still confusing that it only sometimes error'd when I didn't have the   require 'aws/s3' # Needed for Delayed_job in the model. thanks